# Передача значения из data-* в input во всплывающем окне

Tags: html, input

Есть всплывающее окно с контактной формой, в которой есть инпут. Его значение надо менять в зависимости от кнопки, на которую нажал пользователь. Для чего я решил использовать значение data-*.

Опробованные мной решения с просторов не работают. Например, это:

```
<a data-auto="1123" class="btn-success">Заказать</a>

<form>
<input id="someuniqid" type="text" readonly>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>

<script>
$('a.btn-success').on('click',function(){
var mysuperdata = $(this).attr('data-auto');
$('input#someuniqid').val(mysuperdata);
alert("ох ты ж епт");
});
</script>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать разумно и\или почему не работает решение.

Comment: ну почему у меня работает, подскажите а всплывающее окно не подгружается аяксом?

Comment: https :// rent- auto92.ru/ prices/ (убрать пробелы)
Нажмите заказать напротив "Chevrolet Aveo". Не работает даже без окна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя перебивает перехват, который стоит ниже

```
jQuery('.btn-success').click(function() {
```

чем твой

```
$('a.btn-success').on('click',function(){
```

варианты исправить понятны?

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста, я так и не осилил javascript.

Comment: Ну размести код двух функций в одной

Comment: У меня не вышло, подскажешь? А еще подскажи плз как ты определил, что один код перебивает другой?